# Create categorical variable for batch processing in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I want to create a new column in my table that holds value 1 for the first 100,000 row, 2 for the next 100,000 rows and so on.
This is necessary (or so I think) because the server where Oracle is running on aborts all requests after 30 minutes and I know that with the request that I want to run, 100,00 records is on the safe side to be processed.
I looked into CREATE SEQUENCE but it is not what I need.
What I've got so far:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (new_colNUMBER(3,0));  
UPDATE SET new_col = ...
```

I am also open to suggestions on how to tackle this from a different angle.

EDIT My Oracle Version is 12c Enterprise.

Comment: You should definitely be investigating why your batch job abends and fix that, rather than adding a meaningless column to your table.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `DBMS` version is `12c`, then you can add an existing sequence as `default` with `not null` constraint option to populate the initial values, and to provide new values for the upcoming records

```
alter table mytable 
add new_col integer 
default seq_odeme.nextval not null;
```